# ServiceStack Plugin How to add MimeType for new file suffix, and allow the file suffix to be served?

Tags: servicestack

I would like to add the file suffix ".wasm" to the AllowFileExtensions property of the AppHost, and I'd like to associate the MimeType "application/wasm" to that file suffix, so that a Windows service based on ServiceStack can serve static files with this suffix.  In my plugin's Configure method, I've tried this code, but it is not working.

```
public void Configure(IAppHost appHost) {
  // Add the MIMEType application/wasm and associate it with .wasm files
  MimeTypes.ExtensionMimeTypes["wasm"] = "application/wasm";
  // Allow static files ending in .wasm to be served
  var config = new HostConfig();
  var allowFileExtensions = config.AllowFileExtensions;
  allowFileExtensions.Add(".wasm");
}
```

Requests to my ServiceStack Windows service for static files ending in .wasm return a 403 error, and the Content-Type in the response headers is "text/plain".

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong, and how best to allow the new suffix and associate the new MimeType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added `wasm` file extensions to ServiceStack's allowed File Extensions list in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/fee65bac3e815c181a6b135d9d0471ca8cdd5c34). This change is available from v5.1.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

For earlier versions of ServiceStack you can register an allowed File Extension by modifying `IAppHost.Config`, e.g:

```
public void Register(IAppHost appHost) 
{
    appHost.Config.AllowFileExtensions.Add("wasm");
}
```

You don't need to register a MimeType for `wasm` as the default MimeType for unknown Content-Types is `application/{ext}` which for `.wasm` returns `application/wasm`.

Comment: I've been wanting to add a `.xlsx` file extension, to allow simple structured data to be downloaded as a spreadsheet.  My impression was this was impossible without recompiling SS from scratch - is this actually the case?

Comment: Thank you very much. The new 5.1.1 package does indeed add <code>wasm</code>. However, once delivery of static .wasm files began working, the app began requesting  .dll files, which again produced 403 errors. I have added another feature request for dll files, as application/octet-stream.   But I would sure like to understand if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I can see via debugging that I've added "dll" to AllowFileExtensions, and using the Immediate Window (Visual Studio 2017) MimeTypes.ExtensionMimeTypes["dll"] displays "application/octet-stream". But the application returns a 403 for these files. Since they come from the same dir as the .wasm file, the dir permissions must be OK, and the file security permissions are the same as for the wasm file being successfully delivered. Is there anything else I'm missing, that I need to change, to get static .dll files delivered with status code 200, instead of 403?

Comment: @jklemmack You can just add the ext to `Config.AllowFileExtensions` and register MimeType in `MimeTypes.ExtensionMimeTypes[ext] = mimeType`. But I've just pre-registered office extensions + MimeTypes on latest v5.1.1 on MyGet.

Comment: @BillHertzing I can download `.dll` files after `dll` was added to Config.AllowFileExtensions (which is now added by default). You must have something else preventing downloading `.dll` files. Have a look at the Response Body to see if it tells you what's preventing it (e.g. IIS) as if it's in Config.AllowFileExtensions ServiceStack will allow it.

Comment: @mythz Even if the extension is allowed, how would I create a custom response formatter?  Just like one can add `.csv` or `.json` to any request to get a specific format, I'd like `.xlsx` to be available as well.  I'd like to wrap this in a plug-in using something like https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/.  I could perhaps use a response filter, but that seems ... hacky.

Comment: @jklemmack Have a look at how [CsvFormat](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Formats/CsvFormat.cs) is registered.

Comment: @mythz Ack!  My savior!  Either there was a restructuring since I last looked at this, or my groking of SS was woefully incomplete.